# Silverlight UserControl with DataContext Change issue

Tags: silverlight, datacontext

I have created a usercontrol and i consumed in my mainPage.and I have UserControlViewModel and MainPageViewModel.

I have added UsercontrolViewModel in UserControlViewModel as a property with property   name  as usercontrolViewModelContext.so I have DataContext for the mainpage is MainPageViewModel. Then I consumed the UserControl from mainpage and i set the DataContext as usercontrolViewModelContext.

After that I added DataContextChanged event handler for usercontrol in usercontrol.xaml.cs. And in the handler method i am throwing **custom exception** for ex., **InvalidOperationException("Invalid Data Assigned")**.

My issues is,
    I Rebuild the application. then i closed mainpage.xaml and opened. Now I get the Error message opened and also xaml parser error as **"Invalid Data Assigned"** which is thrown exception from datacontextchanged handler method in usercontrol.xaml.cs.

Note: The xaml parser error showing in the design time only.

`<uc:ErrorMessage DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModelContext}" />`

here I am getting the blue underlined in the Datacontext it says my custom message.

Thanks in Advance

nizamd

Comment: It would be beneficial if you posted some code for others to examine

Comment: Cant say I've ever seen an exception with the words "Invalid Data Assigned". Can you post the whole exception, and perhaps some of your xaml and code to go with it?

Comment: "Invalid Data Assigned" is an custom exception where i defined in the datacontext changed event handler method

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue in one of the Visual studio version. This is fixed in VS 2015.